# PDO column of bit type gets no value

Tags: php, pdo

I am querying my mysql-db using PDO, with a plain "SELECT * FROM Invoices" query. Now all columns of type "bit" gets a blank value if i do print_r on the result from the query

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [Client] => 1
            [Title] => Mars 2012
            [Issued] => 2012-04-02
            [Expiration] => 2012-04-22
            [OurReference] => 1
            [TheirReference] => 
            [Payed] => 
            [Sent] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Client] => 4
            [Title] => Apputveckling
            [Issued] => 2012-04-30
            [Expiration] => 2012-05-21
            [OurReference] => 1
            [TheirReference] => 
            [Payed] => 
            [Sent] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [Client] => 4
            [Title] => Administration
            [Issued] => 2012-05-28
            [Expiration] => 2012-06-18
            [OurReference] => 1
            [TheirReference] => 
            [Payed] => 
            [Sent] => 
        )

)
```

How can that be?
This is the getData-method im using

```
public function getData($sql, $data = null)
{
    $statement = $this->query($sql, $data);
    try
    {
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " ";
        return array();
    }

    if(count($result) > 1)
    {
        return $result;
    }
    else if(count($result) == 1)
    {
        return $result[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the rows do have values in the fields in the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit fields are mapped to booleans. A boolean `false` will be printed by `print_r` in exactly the way you see in your question. Here is a test script showing that:

```
$a = array(new stdClass());
$a[0]->Payed = false;
print_r($a);
```

Use [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) instead and you should be able to see both the datatype of each property as well as the boolean content.

Comment: Ahh that explains it...
How could i use that with json_encode to print "true" or "false" depending on the bit value?

    `$invoices = $DB->getData('SELECT * FROM Invoices');`
    `echo json_encode($invoices);`